# Quotient space of a circle action on the 5-sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, homology-cohomology, group-actions, quotient-spaces

I have a question during reading the paper $O(2)$-actions on the 5-sphere (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01389237).

A pseudofree $S^1$-action on a sphere $S^{2k-1}$ is a smooth $S^1$-action which is free except for finitely many exceptional orbits whose isotropy types $\Bbb Z_{a_1},\dots,\Bbb Z_{a_n}$ have pairwise relatively prime orders. Suppose we have given a pseudofree $S^1$-action on $S^5$. In the second page of the paper, it is written that it is easy to see that the quotient space $X:=S^5/S^1$ is a 4-manifold with isolated singularities whose neighborhoods are cones on lens spaces corresponding to the exceptional orbits of the action, and that $X$ is simply connected and $H_2(X;\Bbb Q)=\Bbb Q$. I can see that $X$ is a 4-manifold with isolated singularities corresponding to exceptional orbits, and that $X$ is simply connected. But I can't see why the followings are true:

1. How do we know that neighborhoods of singularities of $X$ are cones on lens spaces?
2. How do we know that $H_2(X;\Bbb Q)=\Bbb Q$?

Comment: By the way, have the feeling that the argument I gave for 2 is probably the correct way to go, but still can't make it work completely, so I sketch it in the comments. In particular it proves that $b_{2}(X) >0$.  If  Y is the $S^5$ minus neighbourhoods of all of the exceptional orbits then $b_{2}(Y)=0$ by Mayer-Vietoris. Then one can consider the Gysin sequence for the smooth $S^1$-bundle $Y \rightarrow Y/S^1$, then one gets that $b_{2}(Y)>0$ and further $b_{2}(Y)=1$ if the map $Y \rightarrow Y/S^1$ induces an isomorphism on $\pi_{1}$. This is the part which alludes me...

Comment: The problem is that the $S^1$ fibre could non-trivial in $\pi_{1}(Y)$ a priori (even though it is clearly trivial in $\pi_{1}(S^5)$), and in particular then the quotient won't induce an isomorphism on $\pi_1$. Provided that one can fix this and prove $b_{2}(Y/S^1)=1$ then note that adding the quotients of the neighbourhoods of the fixed points won't change $b_{2}$ by Mayer-Vietoris.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. 

This is due t the classification of representations of finite cyclic groups and the equivariant slice theorem. I have written a kind of "sketch" of the argument, please ask me if you want more details.

Suppose that $p$ with isotropy group $\mathbb{Z}_a$ where $a>0$ is an integer. Then, in other words, $p$ is a fixed point of the action of $\mathbb{Z}_a \subset S^1$. Hence, $T_pS^5$ inherits the structure of $\mathbb{Z}_a$-representation. Due to the classification of representations of these finite groups , if $\xi = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{a}}$, then under an identification $T_{p}(S^5) = \mathbb{C}^2 \oplus \mathbb{R}$, the action looks like the action $\xi. (z_1,z_2,x) = (\xi^{w_1}z_1, \xi^{w_2} z_2,x)$. Note that the $\mathbb{R}$ factor will be exactly the tangent space of the exceptional orbit. When taking the orbit we quotient "exactly in the direction of the orbit", hence the orbit space is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2/\mathbb{Z}_a$, one may verify that it is homeomorphic to a cone on the lens space.

Then, by the equivariant slice theorem (see  Audins book "Torus actions on symplectic manifolds, Birkhauser, 2004" Theorem I.2.1 ), this is a local model of the point in the quotient space and the claim follows.

Comment: Thanks. For 1, do you mean Bredon's "Topology and Geometry"?

Comment: I meant the book "transformation groups"

Comment: Here is a precise reference Audins book "Torus actions on symplectic manifolds, Birkhauser, 2004" Theorem I.2.1